# The trace of an operator

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory, harmonic-analysis, trace

My question is derived from A. Deitmar's book: *A First Course in Harmonic Analysis* (second edition), p22, Exercise 1.17. Let me rewrite it again:

Let $k:\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ be smooth (i.e., infinitely differentiable) and invariant under the natural action of $\mathbb{Z}^2$; i.e., $k(x+k,y+l) = k(x,y)$ for all $k,l \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$. For $\varphi \in C(\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z})$ set
$$
K \varphi(x) = \int^1_0 k(x,y)\varphi(y)dy.
$$
Show that $K$ satisfies 
$$
\| K \varphi \|^2_2 \leq \| \varphi \|^2_2 \int^1_0 \int^1_0 |k(x,y)|^2 dxdy.
$$
Show that the sum 
$$
\text{tr}K=\sum_{k \in \mathbb{Z}} \langle K e_k, e_k \rangle
$$
converges absolutely and that 
$$
\text{tr}K = \int^1_0 k(x,x)dx.
$$

---

This following inequality 
$$
\| K \varphi \|^2_2 \leq \| \varphi \|^2_2 \int^1_0 \int^1_0 |k(x,y)|^2 dxdy
$$
is easy to verify.

Using the method of integration by parts, I can prove the sum converges absolutely.

**My question is:**
How to prove the following equation 
$$
\text{tr}K = \int^1_0 k(x,x)dx ~? 
$$

This problem has been bothering me for a long time. Thanks in advance.

Comment: "Using the method of integration by parts, I can prove the sum converges absolutely" Hmm? What sum? How?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\{ e_{j} \}$ be an orthonormal basis of $L^{2}[0,1]$ consisting of real functions. Define $f_{i,j}(x,y)=e_{i}(x)e_{j}(y)$. Then $\{ f_{i,j} \}_{i,j}$ is a complete orthonormal basis of $L^{2}([0,1]\times[0,1])$; this can be verified by showing that $(f,f_{i,j})=0$ for all $i$, $j$ for a continuous $f(x,y)$ implies $f=0$. Notice that
$$
\begin{align}
        (k,f_{i,j})_{L^{2}([0,1]\times[0,1])} & =\int_{[0,1]\times[0,1]}k(x,y)e_{i}(x)e_{j}(y)\,dx\,dy  \\
     & =\int_{0}^{1}\left(\int_{0}^{1}k(x,y)e_{j}(y)\,dy\right)e_{i}(x)\,dx \\
     & = (Ke_{i},e_{j})
\end{align}
$$
Therefore,
$$
                k(x,y) = \sum_{i,j}(k,f_{j,k})_{L^{2}([0,1]\times[0,1])}f_{j,k}(x,y) \\
         k(x,x)=\sum_{j,k}(Ke_{j},e_{k})e_{j}(x)e_{k}(x).
$$
Integrating gives
$$
    \int_{0}^{1} k(x,x)\,dx= \sum_{j}(Ke_{j},e_{k})(e_{j},e_{k})=\sum_{j}(Ke_{j},e_{j})= \mbox{tr}(K).
$$

Comment: Using the orthonormal basis in $L^2([0,1])\times[0,1])$ maybe an another good way to this problem. Sorry, I forgot to explain the meaning of $e_k$, that is, $e_k(x)=e^{2k\pi ix}$. Hence, $(Ke_j, e_j)=\int^1_0 Ke_j(x) \overline{e_j(x)}dx$.

Comment: The first property normally proved about trace is that it is independent of the orthonormal basis chosen to compute $\sum_{j}(Ke_{j},e_{j})$. So you can use your favorite basis.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trace_class_operator

Comment: Yes, you are right. As far as for this exercise, we can choose the basis $f_{i,j}(x,y)=\overline{e_i(x)}e_j(y)$. this is because if $(f,f_{j,j})=0$ for any $j$, then we have $f=0$. But the validity of the equation $\int^1_0 k(x,x)dx=\sum_{j,k}(Ke_j,e_k)(e_j,e_k)$ is under the assumption that $\sum_{j,k}|(Ke_j,e_k)|<\infty$ (Is this true?).  Another fact is that this property $k(x+k,y+l)=k(x,y)$ in the exercise do not appear in you proof. I don't know why.

Comment: For the basis elements you have, everything is okay. But, you're right to object in general because $k(x,x)$ is the restriction of $k(x,y)$ to a set of measure 0 in the square. Is there something I'm missing about your problem? Are you considering functions somewhere other than on $[0,1]$ somewhere that I missed?

Comment: Sorry, I have made a mistake in my proof that from $(f,f_{j,j})=0$ to get $f=0$. To exchange the order of integral and sum can we get this equation $\int^1_0 k(x,x)dx=\sum_{j,k}(Ke_j,e_k)(e_j,e_k)$. The precondition is that $\sum_{j,k}|(Ke_j,e_k)|<\infty$.

Comment: Look at the definition of trace class on wikipedia. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trace_class .

Comment: From the website you have mentioned, it only says that the sum $\sum_{k}(Ke_k,e_k)$ is absolutely convergent. This is to be proved in the exercise but not my question. Here, I want to know whether the sum $\sum_{j,k}(Ke_j,e_k)$ is absolutely convergent (the indexs have two elements $j,k$). If it is, then we can exchange the integral and the sum and your answer is perfectly correct.

Comment: I don't get what you want for a general basis $\{ e_{k} \}$, but, for the exponential basis, $\sum_{k,j}(Ke_{k},e_{j})$ is absolutely convergent because you can integrate by parts a couple of times in each direction in order to get $(Ke_{j},e_{k})\le Cj^{-2}k^{-2}$ for $j,k \ne 0$. That uses the assumption that $K$ is smooth and all derivatives are periodic and bounded.

Answer (score 1):

Can we [accept as fact](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_function#Resolutions_of_the_identity) the following representation of the delta function?
\begin{align}
\delta(x-y) = \sum_{j\in \mathbb{Z}} e_{j}(x)\overline{e_{j}(y)}
\end{align}
If so, then
\begin{align}
\mathrm{tr}(K) 
&= \sum_{j\in \mathbb{Z}} \int_{0}^{1}Ke_{j}(x)\overline{e_{j}(x)} \, \mathrm{d}x \\
&=
\sum_{j\in \mathbb{Z}} \int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}k(x,y)e_{j}(y)\overline{e_{j}(x)} \, \mathrm{d}y \,  \mathrm{d}x \\
&=
\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}k(x,y)\sum_{j\in \mathbb{Z}} e_{j}(y)\overline{e_{j}(x)} \, \mathrm{d}y \,  \mathrm{d}x  \qquad \text{(due to absolute convergence)}\\
&=
\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}k(x,y)\delta(x-y) \, \mathrm{d}y \,  \mathrm{d}x\\
&=
\int_{0}^{1}k(x,x) \, \mathrm{d}x
\end{align}
If you can't accept the resolution of identity, you'll probably need to choose an explicit representation of each $e_{j}$ then use the [Dirichlet kernel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_kernel) to do essentially what is done here, but with more pain.

Comment: I don't know exactly what the meaning of this integral $\int^1_0 k(x,y)\delta(x-y)dy$. (It is just like a convolution between $k(x,y)$ with $\delta$. However, it is really an intrgral with real variable). Moreover, I have thought this way: $\sum^{n}_{k=-n}\langle Ke_k,e_k \rangle=\int^1_0\int^1_0 k(x,y)\frac{\sin(2n+1)\pi(y-x)}{\sin \pi(y-x)}dydx$. There has singularity in these places(since $n\rightarrow\infty$): $\{(x,y)\in[0,1]^2: x=y\}$, $(x,y)=(1,0)$ and $(x,y)=(0,1)$. I'm thinking about the details of the proof.